# How to use the new StateRestorationPolicy in Java/Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

Since this topic is fairly new, could someone tell me how to use this feature?
I am trying to use it in a fragment.

```
 override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
...
Handler().postDelayed({
        homePostAdapter!!.stateRestorationPolicy =
            RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
    },500)
...
}
```

Doesn't seem to work like this. Happy to paste the complete fragment class.

For future reading, these links help:

1. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/restore-recyclerview-scroll-position-a8fbdc9a9334
2. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy

Answer (score 3):

Check if your views have ids in XML:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView 
               [...]
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/nestedScroll"> <-- my restore didn't work because I didn't have this id set up

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
                          [...]
             />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

And just set your `stateRestorationPolicy` as:

```
homePostAdapter!!.stateRestorationPolicy = RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```

Comment: just wanna ask I have to save and restore the recycler view position when switching between different activities and fragments will it help me out with that and should i add this in onCreate

Comment: @VasantRaval It will and you can add it in onCreate or wherever you instantiate your adapter

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this will work for you .

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val binding = FragmentMovieActionBinding.bind(view)
        val pagingAdapter =PagingAdapter(lifecycleScope)
        binding.apply {
            rvListTypesMovies.apply {
                adapter= pagingAdapter
                pagingAdapter.stateRestorationPolicy =  RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
                layoutManager =GridLayoutManager(requireContext(), 2)
                setHasFixedSize(true)
```

Im using databinding and also Flow.

Answer (score 2):

For the state restoration to work, the `View` needs to have set `android:id` in layout.xml. Views without ids are not restored.

It doesn't seem to be the case here, but with DataBinding and without `RelativeLayout` ids appear to be unnecessary - but they're still needed to save and restore state.

Comment: this answer doesn't add anything new - can you at least provide examples - codes?

Comment: @KhalodaRK84 View id is rather basic concept when it comes to Android Views. IMHO an example wouldn't help people who don't know what it is already. I've added this answer for the sake of completeness, because it is one of the reasons that disable state restoration, and a different one than the other (at the time of writing) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this in your gradle file

```
implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha04"
```

Comment: That's not what I wanted. Kindly read the question. Do you have an idea on how to use it in a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the delay. You just need to set the `stateRestorationPolicy` just after you initialize your list adapter.

```
 listAdapter = ListAdapter()

 // Set scroll restore policy
 listdapter.stateRestorationPolicy =
      RecyclerView.Adapter.StateRestorationPolicy.PREVENT_WHEN_EMPTY
```